# Unable to contact WCF Service from VPN Connected Machine

Tags: .net, wcf, vpn

I have created a WCF Service in a Server using netTcpBindind. I am able to access the service when I run the WCF client at office. But I am getting the error message "The server has rejected the client credentials." when I run the same WCF Client at home connected to my office network using VPN. (Office Laptop with same Domain). 
Note: I use the same laptop at home and in office. (Domainname\Dickson)

Here is the WCF Service Configuration Settings running in server.

```
<services>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="DTATDataEngine.DTATServiceBehaviour" name="DTATDataEngine.DTATService">     

    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DTATDataEngine.IDTATService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>        
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8523/DTATService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DTATDataEngine.DTATServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Someone can help me on this!

Many Thanks,
Dickson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where's your `<bindings>` section, and more importantly, the `<security>` section of your `netTcpBinding`? I guess the default security for net.tcp is Transport, which uses a Windows client credential.

Your work PC logs onto the domain and thus is authenticated, while your home PC only is in a workgroup and cannot authenticate to your service running in the domain.

Comment: Thanks! The <bindings> is given with in the endpoint itself. Also I use the same Laptop both in office and at home. I just connect to my office domain using RSA via VPN.

Please correct me if I am wrong in the config settings.